# How to get information from an edit text that is entered by the user and move it to another activity as a TextView

Tags: java, android

I need to get information thats entered by the user in a EditText and move it to another activity by placing it under everything with a TextView. I'm new to this, and I'm sure it's simple. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to do what you say you want to do, not exactly. You want to pass the information from one Activity to another, not the actual view.

At the point where you're launching the new activity:

```
String info = editText.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("info_key", info);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in your `onCreate()` in the new Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String info = intent.getStringExtra("info_key");
textView.setText(info);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've almost got it. I guess i'm missing something. I get two errors. One is from where i launch the new activity. The editText is getting an error, from the code you posted above. Should I place the editText's id there? Aslo, the second error comes from the onCreate. the textView from your code above is getting an error. Again, i'm sure this is simple. Beginner. @kcoppock

Comment: Well yeah, you have to substitute your own variables there. Whatever EditText you have a reference to and need the information from, use that instead. Same for the textView.

Comment: I'm positive this is an easy fix. I've tried putting the Id's I've assigned to the EditText and TextView. If thats what you meant by reference. Neither have worked. @kcoppock

Comment: Not meaning to be rude, but you really should first learn how to use Views before moving on to moving between Activities. See [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)

Comment: Alright, that link fixed my problem. Thanks for the help. @kcoppock